# Extra attributes from join table in a has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Recipe`, `Ingredient`, and `RecipeIngredient`.

```
class Recipe
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, through: :recipe_ingredients
end
```

My `RecipeIngredient` has additional attributes like `amount`, `unit`, `type`, etc.

If I wanted from a `recipe.ingredients` to retrieve these extra attributes, how would I go about that in a way that ideally does not introduce N+1 queries or anything else that degrades performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ingredients = recipe.ingredients.all
recipe_ingredients = recipe.recipe_ingredients.all

# only two queries. no queries beyond this point

ingredients.each do |ingredient|
  recipe_ingredient = recipe_ingredients.find {|it| it.ingredient_id == ingredient.id }
  recipe_ingredient.amount # etc
end
```

Something like that perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

**Untested but you can get back to me**

Your question is a little vague but I think this is what you are looking for:

```
recipe = Recipe.includes(:ingredients).find(1)
```

Of course you can replace the `find(1)` with `all` or whatever method you want to use.

Then when you select an attribute from one of the ingredients of a recipe, it won't generate another query since it will have already fetched it.

Reference:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes